# Creating Azure API Management tags in Powershell

Tags: azure, powershell, tags, azure-api-management

Is there a method of creating Azure API Management Tags in Powershell? I have used the [Set-AzApiManagementProperty](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.apimanagement/set-azapimanagementproperty?view=azps-3.1.0) to created Named Values but there does not appear to be an equivilent in AzAPIManagement for the creation of tags.

Any one done this previously?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`New-AzResource`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/new-azresource?view=azps-3.1.0) to create the tag, try the script below, it creates a tag named `tag1`.

```
$ResourceName = "tag1"
$PropertiesObject = @{
    displayName = "tag1"
}
New-AzResource -PropertyObject $PropertiesObject -ResourceGroupName <resource-group-name> -ResourceType Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/tags -ResourceName "<API-Management-service-name>/$ResourceName" -ApiVersion 2018-01-01 -Force
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi Joy, I get an error when running that statement, 

New-AzResource : {"Message":"The requested resource does not support http method 'PUT'."}
At line:3 char:1
+ New-AzResource -PropertyObject $PropertiesObject -ResourceGroupName $ ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [New-AzResource], ErrorResponseMessageException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Cmdlets.Implementation.NewAzureResourceCmdlet

Comment: @PhilMurray Try to update the powershell version via `Update-Module -Name Az -Force`.

Comment: Just updated the Az libraries and rerun the command a I get the same error

Comment: @PhilMurray Could you make sure your script is exactly the same as mine? Could you provide your complete script in your question?

Comment: @PhilMurray Just copy and paste, change the `tag1`, `<resource-group-name>`, `<API-Management-service-name>`, could it work?

Comment: Just took your script again and ran it directly and it works. Obviously something I did wrong when replacing some parameters. Thanks Joy.

Comment: @JoyWang, I find difficult to find all allowed values for `ResourceType` parameter of `New-AzResource`. Is there a specific place of MS docs for this informations?

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look here:

[How to Add Tags to api of APIM via powershell script](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/21817)

Comment: Hi Markus, I have seen that previously. It seems to be for adding existing Tags to a new API. Might be missing something though